# Two tables - how to delete rows if ID not referenced in both tables

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete

I have two tables:

```
listings(item_id, ...)
images(item_id,  ...)
```

The item_id value is the same in both tables - but I goofed and deleted listings from the 'listings' table without also deleting the corresponding row in the 'images' table.

So - I want to delete all rows in the second 'images' table if item_id in IMAGES doesn't correspond to any of the more up-to-date item_id values in my primary 'listings' table.

How do you delete all records in the 'images' table that are not referenced from 'listings'?

I've been experimenting with a SQL script and sub-query like this:

```
DELETE FROM images WHERE item_id IN
(SELECT item_id FROM images EXCEPT SELECT item_id FROM listings)
```

But before I screw it all up, want to confirm if this is correct?

Comment: There is no EXCEPT statement in MySQL

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use a sub query

```
DELETE FROM images WHERE item_id NOT IN(SELECT item_id FROM listings)
```

More [examples and explanation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177682.aspx).

Comment: thanks - this worked great. I'm just learning now about sub-queries!

Answer (score 7):

Here's a nice trick for dealing with these delicate situations:

Before you run a query which may cause significant harm if not written right, replace the DELETE/UPDATE with a SELECT to see which rows your query will affect. In your case, it would be:

```
SELECT * 
-- DELETE
FROM images WHERE item_id NOT IN (SELECT item_id FROM listings)
```

Of course, you also want to cover yourself by backing up the db before issuing such a command. Even when your query looks correct with the SELECT test, you never know...

Comment: Voting up this one only because I really like the idea of the select first, and that's what I always do to make sure I'm getting rid of the right stuff. Otherwise, mine and Dustin's are clearer.

Comment: Agreed about the clarity of the query. I upvoted you guys and updated my answer to suit. I just wanted to get the SELECT, defensive querying trick posted...

Comment: Defensive querying, a real bacon saver!

Answer (score 4):

That would work, or the `IN` clause as well.

```
DELETE
FROM image
WHERE item_id NOT IN (SELECT item_id FROM listings)
```

Answer (score 1):

To me it'd be clearer to say

```
DELETE FROM images WHERE item_id NOT IN 
    (SELECT item_id FROM listings)
```