# SQL Query to delete results of a NOT IN query

Tags: sql

I have a working mysql query which returns all of the people NOT registered in a class.  The SQL is:

```
SELECT * FROM person 
LEFT JOIN attendance 
ON ( person.id = attendance.pid ) 
WHERE (attendance.pid IS NULL
)
```

Now, I want to delete every person in that result.  What's the best way to do this? I tried changing "SELECT *" to "DELETE" and this gave me a syntax error. Any ideas?

Comment: Which database engine are you using?

Comment: I assume you remembered to take out the `*` when trying it with a `delete`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5835589/sql-2-tables-how-to-delete-rows-if-id-not-referenced-in-both-tables/5835619#5835619

Comment: FYI - It's usually a good idea to show exactly what you've tried and the exact message it generated.  For example, the exact delete statement and the "syntax error" is much more important than your original select query.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you're trying to delete all persons without attendance records:

```
 DELETE FROM person WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT pid FROM attendance)
```

Comment: Heads-up: I don't think this works if there are NULL pids in attendance.

Comment: @Derek, that's implementation dependent.  You can deal with it by adding WHERE pid IS NOT NULL to the sub-select.

Comment: @Robert, some engines will not allow any records to match if NULLs show up in the results of the sub-select.

Comment: @Larry: That's fairly counter-intuitive.

Comment: @Robert: "Intuitive" and "NULL" are two words not generally associated with each other, at least in the SQL world.

Comment: This solution worked perfectly for me (in PHPMyAdmin). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try changing it to

```
DELETE person
FROM person 
LEFT JOIN attendance 
ON ( person.id = attendance.pid ) 
WHERE (attendance.pid IS NULL
)
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on engine.
In PL/SQL or maybe another it could be:

```
DELETE FROM person where person.id not in(
   SELECT a.pid FROM attendance a
)
```

[not tested]